# I want to be able to type a percentage into a box into excel, and have all data above that percentage pulled through, is this possible?

Tags: excel, sum, formula, vlookup

I don't know if this is possible or not but here goes, my spreadsheet is as follows:

I have 4 columns- Date, Location, People Attended, % Attended

Going down I have lots of rows with data in. Eg, Date, where the cinic was, how many people turned up, and the percentage of people who booked in to who turned up.

I already have all of this information, but I have been asked if we could have a cell in Excel (can be a different sheet if needed) where we could put in "<65%" and all rows with more than 65% would be pulled through, leaving anything below out. This number could then be changed to any figure we wanted. Is it also possible to have anything above the number we put in, to add the previous column of attended to a total sum?

I hope this makes sense and is formatted correctly, thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this is what works and how you should do it.

- Highlight column a and add a column.
- Add a sheet and name it sheet2 (this is only for now, after you're done you can rename it).
- in sheet2 B1 enter a criteria E.G. `>65` (this will be the cell you'll enter the criteria).
- Back to sheet1. In A2 enter `=IF(COUNTIFS(E2:E2,Sheet2!$B$1&"%")>=1,COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,Sheet2!$B$1&"%"),"")`
- Copy past to all the rows that have your data
- Back to sheet2. in column a starting at row 2 enter numbers from 1 to 100 each number in a separate row, like this A2-1, A3-2 and so on (this will identify the number record the formula should return, if you asume you'll have more then 100 records matching your criteria, add more).
- In sheet2 B2 enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Your table address as absolute ,2,FALSE),"")`
- In C2 enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Your table address as absolute,3,FALSE),"")`
- In D2 enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Your table address as absolute,4,FALSE),"")`
- In E2 enter `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Your table address as absolute,5,FALSE),"")`
- Now copy the formula down all the 100 rows

All the best, hope it works.

Feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you so much! That's brilliant. I can switch it around now to anything I like.

Is it at all possible to make it so we don't have to do > before the number? Just so it's anything greater than the number in that cell?

Comment: Yes sure! if i'd know that that's what you wanted i would of had much an easier time... :) i made it this way so you can choose if you want to see grater or less you just need to change the symbol. if you still want you can just change the `countifs` from `Sheet2!$B$1&"%"` to `">"&Sheet2!$B$1&"%"`

Comment: Ah right, sorry about that! Thank you again, you have been ridiculously helpful.

Comment: Ah, I have just tried replacing the formula but all the numbers change to 0 and nothing else is pulling through, any ideas? sorry about the pestering!

Comment: @George did you change the cell in sheet2 to just a number or it still has the > symbol?

Comment: figured it out, only changed one of the countifs, not both.. Sorry!! Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need any new work! Just use filters (Data tab --> filter).

You can then easily use number filters to get what you are looking for. You can use equality and inequalities (greater/smaller than).

Comment: @George does this solve your problem or you need a better solution? How about using a pivot table?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have specified earlier, for some reason they don't want to use the filter - they are after just a box they could type percentages too and see results. I'm not sure why they're requesting it this way but thought I should check if it was even possible.

Comment: @aFast I will have a play with that, I didn't even consider it. Do you have ideas on how to best utilise it? Cheers

Comment: Yes, it is doable but if I understand you correctly, you need VBA. The concept would be pretty simple (just a programmed way to achieve filtering). 

What I mean can be summarized in the following:
1- Define the cell reference (where you insert the desired number).
2- Create a button or keyboard shortcut to run the filtering code (you may use on change events, which means that the code will run automatically if the cell value is changed).
3- The code would filter the records according to the new value.

Comment: There also is a way to do it just in excel but you'll need to add columns in the sheets. would you do that?

Comment: @aFast Happy to add columns, how would I go about trying this way?

Comment: @George does your data look something like this? [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMzTkeKSoqOS1hYNmRobzgxNmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @aFast Yes, just like that